# declaration of Widgets. In or outside of onCreateView?

Tags: android

whats the diffrence between this two codes:

```
EditText mTitleField;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);
        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
}
```

---

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);
        EditText mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
}
```

The first one has Edittext variable declared outside the onCreateView, the second one has its declaration inside onCreateView.
Does it matter where do I declare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does matter.
For the first scenario, you can use mTitleField with other methods also (though you will have to instatiate it separately for other methods).
For the second scenario, you have bot declared and instantiated mTitleField inside onCreateView(), so it is accessible only inside that method.

This is a basic concept of Global and Local variables in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Off course it does matter, I assume for first case `mTitleField` is declared **globally in class level**. In this case you can access `mTitleField` as `EditText` in any other method in that particular class.

Ex: Suppose on click of any button you need the text enter in that `EditText` then you can simply do like this

```
String someString = mTitleField.getText().toString();
```

---

In second case `mTitleField` is declared locally. In this case outside  `onCreateView(...)` you can not access `mTitleField`. Scope of `mTitleField` is in `onCreateView(...)`.

Ex: Suppose on click of any button you need the text enter in that `EditText` then you have to declare that `EditText` again inside `onClick` method like this

```
EditText mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
String someString = mTitleField.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Difference is that In First Method it declared globally so the advantage of that is you can use global variable anywhere in whole activity While for Second method it is used as a local variable that you can use for Particular place in an activity.

A local variable is defined within the scope of a block.

A global variable is a variable that can be accessed in multiple scopes.